# Noether's Current in QFT with position dependent variations?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

**Setup**

Consider a mapping $F$ that takes every point $x$ on the manifold $M$ to the point $x'$ on the same manifold. Under this mapping the field $\phi(x)$ evaluated at the point $x$ changes to $\phi'(x)$ when evaluated at the same point $x$ on the manifold or $\phi'(x')$ when evaluated at the mapped point $x'$. The action before mapping is given by:
\[S=\int d^Dx \mathcal{L}(\phi(x), \partial_\mu \phi(x),x)\] 
whilst that after mapping is:
$$S'=\int d^D x' \mathcal{L}(\phi'(x'), \partial'_\mu \phi'(x'),x')$$
I am focusing here on the case of QFT, meaning intergrals are over the whole of Minkowski space.

**Noether's Theorem**

According to Noether's theorem a continuous symmetry which leaves the action invariant:
$$\Delta S=S'-S=0$$
corresponds to a conserved quantity.

**The two forms of Noether's Current**

I have come across two forms of Noether's current (Peskin & Schroeder, $\S$2.2):
$$j^\mu(x)=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} \delta \phi - \mathcal{J}^\mu\tag{1}$$
where $\mathcal{J}^\mu$ is defined by the mapping of $\mathcal{L}$: 
$$\mathcal{L}(x) \mapsto \mathcal{L}(x)+\alpha \partial_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu(x)$$
and (Goldstein, 3rd ed, $\S$13.7):
$$j^\nu =\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\nu \phi)}\partial_\sigma \phi-\mathcal{L} \delta^\nu_\sigma\right) X^\sigma-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\nu \phi)} \Psi \tag{2}$$
Where $\delta x^\nu=\epsilon X^\nu$ and $\delta \phi=\epsilon \Psi$.

**Problem with form (1)**

Consider the case of dilation $x^\mu \mapsto (1+\delta\lambda )x^\mu$ then:
$$\mathcal{L}(x) \mapsto \mathcal{L}(x)+\delta \lambda x^\mu \partial_\mu \mathcal{L}$$
here the change in $\mathcal{L}$ can not be written as an exact divergence (also the metric on integration will change). This does not therefore seem compatible with (1).

**Problem with form (2)**

In the derivation of (2) we get the following expression:
$$\int \epsilon \frac{d}{d x^\nu} \left(\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\nu \phi)}\partial_\sigma \phi-\mathcal{L} \delta^\nu_\sigma\right) X^\sigma-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\nu \phi)} \Psi\right)d^4x =0\tag{13.147}$$
from this Goldstein seems to infer that
$$ \frac{d}{d x^\nu} \left(\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\nu \phi)}\partial_\sigma \phi-\mathcal{L} \delta^\nu_\sigma\right) X^\sigma-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\nu \phi)} \Psi\right)=0\tag{13.148}$$
which given that we have a fixed range of integration (the whole of space) I cannot see any reason why this should hold.

**Question**

My question is what is therefore the most general form of Noether's current which can deal with things like scaling? And are my two concerns above justified?

Comment: In (1) you are forgetting the transformation of $d^dx$ ($d$ is dimension of spacetime). Under $x^\mu \to ( 1 + \delta \lambda ) x^\mu$, we have $d^dx {\cal L} \to d^d x ( 1 + d \delta \lambda) ( {\cal L} + \delta \lambda x^\mu \partial_\mu {\cal L} = d^d x [ {\cal L} +  \delta \lambda \partial_\mu ( x^\mu  {\cal L} ) ]$.

Comment: @Prahar Ok I thought it was something to do with this. I guess this therefore means that the contribution $(1+d\delta \lambda)$ is included within the new $\mathcal{L}$? Should we therefore be defining a knew Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}'$ defined as: $$\mathcal{L}'=(1+d \partial_\mu(\delta x^\mu))\mathcal{L}(\phi',\partial'_\mu \phi',x')$$ and will this deal with all such cases?

Comment: The reason for the second current is because "$\epsilon$ is arbitrary". It's the usual thing where we just set the thing proportional to a variation inside the integral to be zero.

Comment: @childofsaturn - that only works if "$\epsilon$ is an arbitrary function". Here, it seems to be an arbitrary constant, which is certainly not good enough.

Comment: @childofsaturn I agree with Prahar. From what I can tell $\epsilon$ does have to be constant.

Comment: @Prahar $\epsilon$ is promoted to a space-time dependent function when deriving the Noether current (the usual trick)

Comment: @childofsaturn - I know what you are talking about but that derivation is not the one that is being followed here, in either (1) or (2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Peskin & Schroeder (1) are only considering situations with purely vertical transformations, so OP's horizontal spacetime dilation transformation does *not* apply. [For terminology, see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195657/2451).] See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301847/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. Goldstein's formula (2) for the bare Noether current $j^{\mu}$ holds for combined horizontal and vertical transformations. The full Noether current $J^{\mu}=j^{\mu}- k^{\mu}$ has a possible improvement term $k^{\mu}$ in case of a [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451).
3. OP is right. The proof from (13.147) to (13.148) is flawed/insufficient as it is written in Goldstein. Noether's conservation law (13.148) is of course correct, but the proof in Goldstein of [Noether's first theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is incomplete.