# Expansion of $\mathcal{L}(\phi'(x'),\partial_\mu'\phi'(x'),x')$ when looking at Noether's current

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I just asked this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369729/) concerning the application of Noether's theory. Think about this got me wondering about the following. In the usual derivation of the Noether current the assumption is made that:

$$\mathcal{L}(\phi'(x'),\partial_\mu'\phi'(x'),x')=\mathcal{L}(\phi(x),\partial_\mu\phi(x),x)+\delta x^\mu\partial_\mu\mathcal{L}(\phi(x),\partial_\mu\phi(x),x).\tag{1}$$
This is usually shown by considering the Lagrangian to be a function of $x$ only then, the statement that:

$$\mathcal{L}(x')=\mathcal{L}(x)+\delta x^\mu\partial_\mu\mathcal{L}(x)\tag{2}$$

does indeed hold true by trivial Taylor expansion. But as far as I can tell this derivation is making the assumption that:
$$\phi'(x')=\phi(x').\tag{3}$$
I have seen (1) used in cases where this is not the case. Thus please can someone explain why (1) holds for a general mapping $\phi(x) \mapsto \phi'(x')$

Comment: Formula (1) does not hold for a general variation.

Comment: @Qmechanic, Oh ok, now I am confused. Do you know any sources that derive the Noether's current in QFT for a general case?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Actually, believe it or not, the wiki page is great. Look for the fiber bundle derivation.

Comment: @Qmechanic eq (1) is actually fairly general under Dirichlet boundary conditions. Sure, it's (or looks like) a taylor expansion, but you can get to this result by formal variational techniques without expanding in small variations.

Comment: @Qmechanic If you have time I would be interested in your response to BB681 comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general variation$^1$ 
$$ \delta {\cal L}~=~\delta_0 {\cal L} + \delta x^{\mu}~d_{\mu}{\cal L} \tag{A}$$
of the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ is a sum of

1. a vertical$^2$ variation $$\delta_0 {\cal L}
   ~=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \phi^{\alpha}} ~\delta_0\phi^{\alpha} +\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \phi^{\alpha}_{,\mu}} ~d_{\mu}\delta_0\phi^{\alpha}\tag{B}$$ (which OP's eqs. (1) & (2) are missing), and
2. a transport term $$\delta x^{\mu}~d_{\mu}{\cal L}\tag{C}$$ from a horizontal$^2$ variation $\delta x^{\mu}$.

--

$^1$ In this answer we will for simplicity only consider *infinitesimal* variations/transformations.

$^2$ For terminology, see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195657/2451).

Comment: Great thanks for your answer. Does the variation $\delta \mathcal{L}$ include the variation in the Jacobian as mentioned by Prahar in a [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369729/noethers-current-in-qft-with-position-dependent-variations#comment827278_369729) to one of my previous questions

Comment: No, the Jacobian has not yet been taken into account.